# Dynamic Comparison Operator in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way have a dynamic comparison operator in Oracle PL/SQL? I have a while loop that looks something like this...

```
WHILE counter > workingDays
LOOP...
```

I'm simplifying a bit, but if the current day is a weekend, I'd love for that `>` to actually be `>=`. Is there any way to have a dynamic comparison operator in PL/SQL? This doesn't work, but something like this...

```
operator := '>';

IF TO_CHAR( curDate, 'D') IN (1,7) THEN operator = '>=';

WHILE counter operator workingDays
LOOP...
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, using dynamic SQL; but aren't you complicating things?

Why use a dynamic operator, instead of using standard Boolean operators to build your condition? Something like

```
counter > workingDays or (<<sysdate is a weekend>> and counter = workingDays)
```

(I used some pseudocode - I assume you know how to write the condition on `sysdate`.)

Or use a `case` expression:

```
counter > workingDays - case when <<sysdate is a weekend>> then 1 else 0 end
```

Such approaches are always more robust and more efficient than any dynamic solutions to the same problem.